# How do you find the size of a particle in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

How do you find the size of a particle in Three.js?

With geometrys you can use the bounding box/sphere to calculate its size in three.js units. But a particle has no bounding box and I can't see of anyway to calulate its size.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what meaning of 'particle' you are dealing with. With a `WebGLRenderer` you would be referring to a vertex in a `ParticleSystem`, but with a `CanvasRenderer` you mean `Particle` (which is Canvas only). In terms of the ParticleSystem the material used to construct it has a size, like in the usual examples:
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10000; i ++ ) {
  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3(); // and set its location
  geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}

material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { 
  size: 35,  // This might be the size you are thinking of?
  sizeAttenuation: false, 
  map: // Some THREE.Texture
});

particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, material );
```

Then you can access the size, and modify it simply with

```
particles.material.size = newSize;
```

If you are creating a `Particle` for canvas, then it is very similar:

```
// Construct the particle with a material
var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { 
  map: new THREE.Texture(  canvas ), 
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending 
}); 
particle = new THREE.Particle( textMaterial );
// Just need to access the material to get the 'size'
var size = particle.material.size
```